# How to design a RESTful API endpoint that returns a suggestion to a user

Tags: rest, restful-architecture

I am building a RESTful API that deals with users and suggestions. I reached the point where I need to build the suggestion resource, which should be **nested** in the user resource and which should return a computed suggestion (this means it doesn't exist yet - it is created on the fly, when the request is made).

I thought of making a route like `users/<id>/suggestion`, but it doesn't feel right: it can be `users/<id>/suggestions` to fetch all this user's suggestions, or `users/<id>/suggestion/<id2>` to fetch a particular suggestion of this user. In this case, I would need to build 3 resources, one to deal with returning a computed suggestion, one to deal with all suggestions and another one to deal with a particular, existing suggestion.

Then, is `GET` appropriate to retrieve a **newly** created, computed, object? It sounds naturally, but I don't know if it's true REST. If not, what method should I use?

I appreciate any help on this. If you wonder what language/framework I'm using, it's partly Flask/Flask RESTful and Rails/Sinatra.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have a couple of options and it depends how you are using the suggestions.

#### Transient model

In the simple case, just support a transient (ie stateless on the server):
/users//suggestions

You could cache it for some time and not actually store any suggestions on the server. In that case, you would probably not offer an individual suggestion API (/users//suggestions/123 not supported). Instead each of the results in the response would be RESTful representations of *other* resources.

ie /users//suggestions could return:

```
[
  {
    "type": "book",
    "name": "Some book",
    "author": "Some author",
    "url": "https://yoursite.com/books/123"
  },
  {
    "type": "movie",
    "name": "Some movie",
    "producer": "Some movie",
    "url": "https://yoursite.com/books/123"
  }
]
```

A variant would be to provide different sections for each type, ie { books: [], movies: [] }. You could also wrap these heterogeneous models in "suggestion" resources with confidence levels etc. But no ID or URL for the suggestion wrapper, because the suggestions don't exist on the server.

#### Persisted model

If you want suggestions to be more like first-class citizens, which could be fetched individually, then you should probably create something like a SuggestionSet resource. It accepts a post request and returns a URL for the new SuggestionSet, e.g. at //suggestion-sets/123. Then the client can do a further GET request to retrieve the set and it will list all the individual items.

An alternative is to pre-build suggestions for every user. Obviously that doesn't scale very well but can be sufficient for a small system. You can also combine it with the approach in the previous example, ie prefetch for active users and still support POST for inactive ones.

You'll want to clean up old suggestion sets periodically.

#### Transient or persisted?

In most cases, the transient model should be fine. The persisted model has two main benefits:

- You can drill into suggestion detail by requesting the individual suggestions as in your question (users//suggestion/). But note those are suggestion wrapper objects containing suggestion metadata (e.g. a comment about why user might like it, a confidence level, etc.), they are not the actual suggested resources the user cases about (e.g. books and movies), which are already obtainable through existing API calls.
- Here's the real benefit - you can deal with suggestions asynchronously. If you make it a GET call, you will need to build all the suggestions in a fraction of a second so they can be returned in a non-blocking response. If you require a POST first, the client can be expected to poll until the suggestion set is ready.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the highly detailed explanation! In my case, indeed, a suggestion will contain several other objects. But the suggestion itself will be stored in the database, so it will exist after a request to my endpoint is made (that's why I mentioned accessing user suggestions or a particular user's suggestion afterwards). In this situation, what would you recommend?

Comment: It partly depends if you want clients to be able to generate suggestions on demand (versus pre-building them, e.g. on a cron-type schedule or as resources are created/updated). If clients should be able to create a bunch of suggestions at once, that's where a SuggestionSet construct is useful. If they are pre-built, you could just serve suggestions on a GET call, it will be quick.

Comment: I understand. And one final question: if a call to `users/<id>/suggestion` fails, what should I return (body+status code)? It can be that the algorithm at the end couldn't build a suggestion (out of the params I also send with the request). Is a 200 + `{}` body OK in this case?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by `users/<id>/suggestion`. If you mean users only ever have one suggestion, then a 404 would probably make more sense. If you mean  `users/<id>/suggestions`, then I'd say 200 with an empty suggestion list is better, will be easier for the client to work with.

Comment: It's the endpoint where you can get a single suggestion from. It's not the same, it's generated every time a request is made. But it might be the case that it cannot be generated, so the response will be empty.

Comment: I don't think you should have a special path to get just one suggestion that's separate from the one for multiple suggestions (you'd only do that for specific suggestions where the request includes their ID, which I don't think you mean). It would be cleaner to just have one endpoint for multiple suggestions (`/user/<id>/suggestions`) and if client wants just one suggestion, the service can support a "limit" param for that. If you implemented it this way, returning zero results would be as simple as `{}` (whether a limit was requested or not).

Comment: I know it's not very RESTful, that's why I asked this in the first place. But having `/user/<id>/suggestions` is useless because there will only be the case to return one suggestion (or none if it couldn't be computed). And always passing the limit param would also be useless since it would have to be passed all the time. I was now thinking of an endpoint like `/user/<id>/suggestions/new`, how's that sound?

Comment: Oh I think `/user/<id>/suggestion` is fine in that case, ie if it's either there or not there (the `/new` is unnecessary and again not really great REST practice for this purpose). I'd just return 404  if a suggestion couldn't be generated. And when you say it's not RESTful, I'd say this *is* RESTful; there's no law that say you have to return multiple objects if your business logic doesn't warrant it.